# Can't indexing an array without using another var

Tags: go

I think is something that I miss theoretically from the passing by reference topic but I can't find a way to read the `ID` without using the support `networkInterfaceReference`

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/profiles/preview/resources/mgmt/resources"
    "github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/services/compute/mgmt/2021-03-01/compute"
    "github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/services/subscription/mgmt/2020-09-01/subscription"
    "github.com/Azure/go-autorest/autorest/azure/auth"
    "github.com/ktr0731/go-fuzzyfinder"
)

var selectedSub subscription.Model
var selectedRG resources.Group
var selectedVM compute.VirtualMachine

func main() {
    selectedSub = GetSubscription()
    selectedRG = GetResourceGroup()
    selectedVM = GetVM()

    fmt.Printf("Sub: %s\nRG: %s\nVM: %s\n", *selectedSub.DisplayName, *selectedRG.Name, *selectedVM.Name)

    // THIS WORK
    networkInterfaceReference := *selectedVM.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaces
    fmt.Printf("%s", *networkInterfaceReference[0].ID)

    // THIS DOESN'T WORK
    fmt.Printf("%s", *selectedVM.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaces[0].ID)
}

...
...
...

func GetVM() compute.VirtualMachine {
    vmClient := compute.NewVirtualMachinesClient(*selectedSub.SubscriptionID)
    authorizer, err := auth.NewAuthorizerFromCLI()
    if err == nil {
        vmClient.Authorizer = authorizer
    }
    vmList, err := vmClient.List(context.TODO(), *selectedRG.Name)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    idx, err := fuzzyfinder.Find(vmList.Values(), func(i int) string {
        return *vmList.Values()[i].Name
    })
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    return vmList.Values()[idx]
}
```

Hovering to the error showed the following error message:

```
field NetworkProfile *[]compute.NetworkProfile
(compute.VirtualMachineProperties).NetworkProfile on pkg.go.dev

NetworkProfile - Specifies the network interfaces of the virtual machine.

invalid operation: cannot index selectedVM.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaces (variable of type *[]compute.NetworkInterfaceReference)compiler (NonIndexableOperand)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the 2nd way to work:

```
// WORKS
networkInterfaceReference := *selectedVM.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaces
fmt.Printf("%s", *networkInterfaceReference[0].ID)

// THIS DOESN'T WORK
fmt.Printf("%s", *selectedVM.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaces[0].ID)
```

studying the compilation error you are getting (P.S. please don't post [screen-shots of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)) - the error is failing because you are trying to index a pointer which is not allowed in Go. You can only index maps, arrays or slices.

The fix is simple, since you do two (2) pointer dereferences in the working version, you need to do two (2) same in the single expression - but also you need to ensure the lexical binding order so the indexing is done after the pointer dereference:

```
fmt.Printf("%s", *(*selectedVM.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaces)[0].ID)
```

---

Finally, there is no pass-by-reference in Go. Everything is by value. If you want to change a value, pass a pointer to it - but that pointer is a still just a value that is copied.

Comment: I have changed the image to the transcription. Thanks for pointing that. Unfortunately, I already tried your solution. I receive the exact same error copy-pasting your code.

Comment: To force lexical binding priority use parentheses. I've updated answer accordingly.